# During Reversed Engineering of htc android application

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, dex2jar

I am trying to decode htc's messaging app's apk file using [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and [apk-tools](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) . I 
reversed more than 30 apps perfectly without any trouble ! but I can't do same thing with htc's app ! can any one help me to get out of this problem?

Problem 1 (While dex2jar decoding) :

[image]

> Note : I also used dex2jar Mms.apk but d2j-dex2jar Mms.apk is more desirable.

Problem 2 (While Getting Resource appk-tool) :

[image]

> I know I need to add com.htc.resource.apk framework but don't know how to do it !

Comment: If you only need smali code of that application you can use `apktool d -r your.apk`, not to bother with resource unpacking. If this works, try to build unpacked content with `apktool` and see `dex2jar` works with newly created apk!

Comment: @Akdeniz : facing same problem. ! i did ! I recompiled apk using 'apktool b Mms Mms.apk' and then try to decode with dex2jar but same error continuing ! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to unpack a system application. `classes.dex` files are ripped from system applications and saved as optimized `ODEX` files. You can read more from [here](http://www.alliance-rom.com/community/wiki/odex-and-deodex/)

So before using `dex2jar` on these APKs, you should convert `ODEX` file back to `DEX` and put them in APK. Or you can just use `dex2jar` on converted `DEX` files..

Comment: Thanks buddy.. can you please tell me how to convert ODEX to DEX ??

Comment: Here you can find `deodex` instructions for `smali/baksmali!` : http://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/DeodexInstructions